# Reverting third party merge in GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-revert

Git gave me this reply:

```
$ git push -u origin master
To https://github.com/xxxxxxx/yyyyyy.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxxxxxx/yyyyyy.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I don't want to integrate any remote changes to my local repository. I have already made many changes in my local repository.
On a GitHub environment I see last commit is:

```
zzzzzzz Merge remote-tracking branch '1/master'
```

That means, user zzzzzzz (not me) made a merge to my remote repo in GitHub. And currently I am out of ideas, how to revert that commit in GitHub. In GitHub I can see only commit hash of that merge, but not any 'revert' button at that. Can I fix it remotely or I have to SSH into GitHub?
Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you allowing other people to merge into your `master` branch (presumably without approval) if you don't want to pull down their changes? Why do you have local changes on `master` that aren't pushed to the origin? There are so many questions here...

Comment: I was just testing a new Android app that syncs with a Git repository.  And this application independently overwrote my file on GitHub.  In essence, he added to that file exactly the same content that was already there.  The problem is that now the git push fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want that commit at all, you can simply force push your own branch (and make sure to have a word with the other contributor)

```
git push --force
```

You can also consider `master` as a [protected branch](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches) and add a [branch protection rule](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule) on it.

That way, no more surprise.

Finally, manage your collaborators list (you can [remove a collaborator](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/removing-a-collaborator-from-a-personal-repository)).